# Is there any annotation in Java for C# Range attribute?

Tags: c#, java, annotations

I was looking into a [Question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583800/new-type-definition-in-c-sharp) where OP wanted to validate the data whether it is within *valid range* or not when creating the object. One possible answer is to use [`Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) attribute.

So is there any way(annotation) in Java to make this happen? Or I have to use good old throwing exception from constructor for invalid entry?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such JDK annotation. If there was, you would still need some annotation processor to do something about it, whether at compile time (add code) or at run time (intercept the method call and apply the behaviour).

> So is there any way(annotation) in Java to make this happen? Or I have
>   to use good old throwing exception from constructor for invalid entry?

There are solutions with [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://www.voelter.de/data/articles/aop/aop.html) (possibly through [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html)), [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), and/or [proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html), but those seem a little advanced for what you want to do. You are better of doing it the old fashioned way.